# vba internet explorer delete object

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I'm making simple vba script witch is gonna open IE, get some informations and exit. Script open IE 35 times without problem, but after that it, works, but doesn't open IE anymore.

```
Sub Test()
for x=1 to 50
    Dim objIE As Object
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.Navigate2 "http://www.google.com"
    objIE.Visible = False
    Set objIE = Nothing
next x
End Sub
```

Comment: have a read of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface  if you are interested in what GDI's are however I believe there is a limit on GDI objects and how many you can open will depend on IE version and if 64 bit or 32 bit version. Are you running latest IE version 64 bit ? This is from my memory of a problem I had some years ago but it may still be relevant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really get what you want do with your code, but here some tips that might help to fix the issue:

1. You can take both the declaration and the set of your browser out of the loop, you don't need to declare it and set it each time:

   ```
   Dim objIE As Object
   Set objIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
   ```
2. Why are you setting `objIE` as  `New InternetExplorer`, if you're right after setting it again as `New InternetExplorerMedium`? That action is useless.
3. Between the `objIE.Navigate2 "http://www.google.com"` and the `Set objIE = Nothing` you should probably wait some time, at least with a `Do While objIE.busy Loop`, because you don't even give the browser the time to load the document and you already destroy it.
4. The `Set objIE = Nothing` can also be put out of the loop, you can re-use the same browser to navigate as many links as you want. Also, don't forget to quit it first before destroying it from memory with `objIE.quit`

If it works 35 times and keep on "working but doing nothing" starting from the 36th, wonder about the links are corrupted when you get there. 
You can check that with a `Debug.Print` on the link you're going to navigate each time.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic structure to automate IE with VBA.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PAO()

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim url As String
    Const url$ = "http://www.google.com"

    Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate url

    Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Also, here is a `Wait` function that can help you to wait for the webpage to load.

```
Function IEWait(t As Long)

    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", t, Now)
    Loop

End Function
```

This is how you use the function:

```
IEWait (1)
Do Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
```

Hope this will help you but let me know if you have any question.